# My jQuery scripts work when i test them in jsfiddle, but not in my HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Everything in my code works so far except the jQuery function. It works completely fine in jsfiddle, but the function does not work in my html file for some reason. I don't think it's that extra characters are appearing when I'm copying because from the HTML file. I haven't changes the HTML file at all i just copy/pasted the code from it to jsfiddle and it started working. Here is a link to the jsfiddle and the code for my html document. If you want to open the program the way it's meant to be, copy/paste the code into the developer tools in a google chrome tab that has all of the elements deleted. The big gap with black squares is where an image is that is based from a local file. The jQuery function is directly above my body element. Also, I am pretty new to coding so the mistake is probably a very obvious one to someone who has been doing this for years.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lukkuss/dshcp1f2/2/

```html
<html><head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link class="" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   

    <title>Is it a good team comp?</title>

     <style>.body-size {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
width: px;
height: 800px; 
background-color: #09c1a9;
}
h3 {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
h1 {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
h2 {
height: 610px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
p {
color: yellow;
width: 650px;
background-image: url("rift map.PNG");  
height: 650px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}   
.img-size {
width: 670px;
height: 670px;
}</style>
  <style> 
  #map-container {
  position: relative;
} 
</style><style>
  #toplane {
  background-color: #0e1821;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px
  }</style>
<style>
  #jungle {
  background-color: #0e1821;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
  }
</style>
<style>
  #midlane {
  background-color: #0e1821;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 325px;
  left: 290px;
  }
</style><style>
  #botlane {
  background-color: #0e1821;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 520px;
  left: 450px;
  }
</style><style>
  #support {
  background-color: #0e1821;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 520px;
  left: 360px;
  }
  </style>
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#4c6ccc");
    });
    $("input").blur(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    });
  });
    </script>
</head>
 <body class="body-size">

  <h1 class="text-center" style="color: #78ff00;">Is it a good team composition?
  </h1>
  <div class="row">
  <div id="map-container">
<p class="col-md-6">Images of the selected champions will appear within the lanes that they are assigned. The program will not functon properly if you do not reset the lane assignments before entering a new team. </p>
  <div id="toplane"></div>
  <div id="jungle"></div>
  <div id="midlane"></div>
  <div id="botlane"></div>
  <div id="support"></div>
</div>
    <h2 class="col-md-4">
  Insert the names of the champions on your team into their respective lanes.
<form>
  <input id="lane-assignment" type="text" placeholder="Top Lane" required=""><br>

  <input id="lane-assignment" type="text" placeholder="Jungle" required=""><br>

  <input id="lane-assignment" type="text" placeholder="Middle Lane" required=""><br>

  <input id="lane-assignment" type="text" placeholder="Bottom Lane" required=""><br>

  <input id="lane-assignment" type="text" placeholder="Suppport" required=""><br>
  <button type="submit">Enter lane assignments
  </button>
<button>
Reset lane assignments
</button></form>*IMPORTANT* The program will not function properly if the champions' names are not spelled correctly.
</h2>
<h3 class="col-md-4">
Pros:                               
Cons:                               
</h3>
  </div>Specific comments about your team will appear here.</body></html>
```

Comment: debugging step 1 - check the browsers **developer** tools console for errors - errors here will greatly help you find why something "does not work for some reason" - in fact, then you'll be able to say it "does not work because <insert reason here>" - a link to working code, then saying "it doesn't work in some arbitrary situation" is almost impossible to debug for you

Comment: You might be better served placing your JQuery at the end of your body content, before the </body> tag. Your issue could be that your function precedes the element being manipulated, and thus has nothing to do since it runs prior to render.

Comment: @TCharb - doing so would break any code like `$(function() { ... stuff to do on document ready ...})` - oh, you meant he should put his **javascript** later ... as jquery isn't a language (so he has no jquery, he has javascript)

Comment: no @TCharb - I think you used the word jquery, which I thought referred to the jquery library :p - the OP's javascript is wrapped in `$(function() { ... })` - so there's no problem with where it is

Comment: Oh no haha, definitely want the library to load before all other elements, in the head.

Comment: ya the library is accessible in my browser, I just tested the placement of the function to see if that mattered, and there are no errors in the console. Yet the input boxes wont focus like the do in jsfiddle.
I did find something interesting though when i was moving the code to directly above the </body> closing tag. A single element that I definitely did not put there.

<jqueryclones style="display: none;"></jqueryclones>

Comment: By the way you should never use the same id twice on the one page. id=lane-assignment is repeated several times. Use a class instead or give each a unique id.

Comment: that jqueryclones element has probably been added by a browser extension. try disabling all browser extensions and run your page again.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine to me as per written javascript / jquery. Have you checked following URL is accessible from your browser?
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js